# WIX one or more Conditional Component with predefined Variables

Tags: wix

Hi based on Environments(UAT,TEST,DEV,PROD) and Server Specific(Server1,Server2..) I am filtering the config files.

```
<Component Id="cmp39F4D3AA1248B5FE5EB2F92D189B27E1" Directory="dirCFCE6D07D3330FE628276777F0488B18" Guid="{56788F77-A729-47CE-BBA4-9D7D7F175536}">
<File Id="fil10B3B7732D0DDBD4AA773E0B7F34D092" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SDirect.B2CWeb.ProjectDir)Web.ProdBuild.Web1.config.xml" >
<CopyFile Id="SCopy_ConfigPROD1" DestinationProperty="DestFilesWebsiteFolder" DestinationName="Web.config" />
</File>
              <Condition> <![CDATA[ENVPROPERTY~="PROD"]]></Condition>
</Component>
```

The Above component works fine; the ENVPROPERTY Property value is set through command line when Installing by MSIEXEC.

But When I change the above statement as below doesn't work where the Installer need to detect the computername or Servername where it gets installed and based on that the installer must make sure to deploy the above component or not.

```
<Component Id="cmp39F4D3AA1248B5FE5EB2F92D189B27E1" Directory="dirCFCE6D07D3330FE628276777F0488B18" Guid="{56788F77-A729-47CE-BBA4-9D7D7F175536}">
<File Id="fil10B3B7732D0DDBD4AA773E0B7F34D092" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SDirect.B2CWeb.ProjectDir)Web.ProdBuild.Web1.config.xml" >
<CopyFile Id="SCopy_ConfigPROD1" DestinationProperty="DestFilesWebsiteFolder" DestinationName="Web.config" />
</File>
    <Condition> <![CDATA[ENVPROPERTY~="PROD" AND ComputerName~="Server1"]]></Condition>
</Component>
```

Can any one help in setting the conditional statement which satisfies ENVPROPERTY="PROD" and ComputerName="Server1" ie the servername(Machine) the MSI package gets installed. So that above components gets deployed and not skipped when package gets deployed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share snippets of the log file that show the values of `ENVPROPERTY`, `ComputerName` and any references to `cmp39F4D3AA1248B5FE5EB2F92D189B27E1` and `56788F77-A729-47CE-BBA4-9D7D7F175536` in the verbose log file. That will help narrow what is going wrong.

Comment: For some reason when I give the condition Vice versa it just woked

Comment: For some reason when I give the condition Vice versa it just worked. Not sure what had happened over their. <Condition> <![CDATA[ComputerName~="Server1" AND ENVPROPERTY~="PROD"]]></Condition> and Property are set correctly only in Log file.

Answer (score 0):

Public Properties only can be used in command line. All letters should be in upper case for public properties. Use **ComputerName** property as **COMPUTERNAME** like the other one.

Comment: ComputerName is a built-in Windows Installer Property. It should be set automatically.